# Java TCP client halts after finishing reading inputstream data from python server

Tags: python, java, sockets, tcp

I'm new to socket programming. I'm trying to implement a java client program whose retrieve function can get the information of whether a file exists in the python server.

If exist, then the server sends `"YES"` to the client.
`self.request.send(b'YES')`.

If not exist, then the server sends `NO` to the client.
`self.request.send(b'NO')`.

The java client will read the byte string in this way.

```
    private void retrieve() throws IOException {
        int len;
        byte[]buffer = new byte[1024];
        String line =null;
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        while((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            line = new String(buffer, 0, len);
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.flush();
        }
    }
```

However, the client program halts after receiving the message from the server.

```
>>> RETRIEVE test.txt
"YES"
//program halts here
```

I expect the output should be

```
>>> RETRIEVE test.txt
"YES"
>>> //continue to input other cmd
```

EDIT: a section of python server code is below. The last few lines are the code for sending messages to the client.

```
class EchoHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    uploading = False
    exiting = False
    filename = None
    line_buffer = []
    saved_files = []

    def handle(self):
        print(timestamp(), 'Got connection from', self.client_address)
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.request.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not msg: break                
                msg_str = str(msg, encoding='utf-8')
                if self.uploading:
                    if msg_str != '#\n':
                        print(timestamp(), 'Line received:', msg_str.rstrip())
                        self.line_buffer.append(msg_str)
                    else:
                        print(timestamp(), 'EOF received:', msg_str.rstrip())

                        # save the received file
                        f = open(self.filename, 'w')
                        f.writelines(self.line_buffer)
                        print(timestamp(), 'Saving to {}'.format(self.filename))
                        self.saved_files.append(self.filename)
                        f.close()

                        # reset file buffer
                        self.filename = None
                        self.uploading = False
                        self.line_buffer = []
                    self.request.send(b'ACK')
                    print(timestamp(), 'Sending ACK')
                    continue

                msg_pieces = msg_str.split()
                command = msg_pieces[0]
                if command in ['UPLOAD', 'DOWNLOAD', 'RETRIEVE']:
                    if len(msg_pieces) < 2:
                        print(timestamp(), 'ERROR: please provide file name')
                        self.request.send(b'ERROR: please provide file name'); time.sleep(SENDING_COOLDOWN)
                    elif len(msg_pieces) > 2:
                        print(timestamp(), 'ERROR: to many arguments')
                        self.request.send(b'ERROR: to many arguments'); time.sleep(SENDING_COOLDOWN)
                    elif command == 'RETRIEVE':
                        self.filename = _extract_filename(msg_pieces[1])
                        if self.filename in self.saved_files:
                            self.request.send(b'YES'); time.sleep(SENDING_COOLDOWN)
                        else:
                            self.request.send(b'NO'); time.sleep(SENDING_COOLDOWN)
```

Comment: Does your Python server send anything after YES or NO?

Comment: Did you forget to post your Python server code?

Comment: @geobreze for the RETRIEVE command, the server only sends YES or NO, no further msg is sent afterward.

Comment: @BrutusForcus For the RETRIEVE command, the code is there :D, or do you mean the code for the entire program?

Comment: @BrutusForcus I have updated the post with a section of python server code that may be useful

Comment: As I see from the code, as for next step, java client should send next command. Does it send it? Or java waits for other message to appear?